# How to play with the Substrate labels?

Tags: documentation

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/labels?page=1&sort=name-asc

Is there a doc for this?

E.G. `E5-breaksapi`

What's the meaning of `E`?

What's the meaning of `5`?

What labels should I pay attention to if I update the Substrate version?

Comment: We are reworking the labels to make them more understandable. The current set of labels is too random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the labels and their meanings are listed here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

> *Labels TLDR:*
>
> - `A-*` Pull request status. ONE REQUIRED.
> - `B-*` Changelog and/or Runtime-upgrade post composition markers. ONE REQUIRED. (used by automation)
> - `C-*` Release notes release-priority markers. EXACTLY ONE REQUIRED. (used by automation)
> - `D-*` More general tags on the PR denoting various implications and requirements.

> Please label issues with the following labels:
>
> - `I-*` Issue severity and type. EXACTLY ONE REQUIRED.
> - `P-*` Issue priority. AT MOST ONE ALLOWED.
> - `Q-*` Issue difficulty. AT MOST ONE ALLOWED.
> - `Z-*` More general tags on the issue, denoting context and resolution.

It seems others are not well documented, and hopefully that will change in the near future as @bkchr mentions.